# Add dynamic property to Linq result set objects

Tags: linq, dynamic

I have object lists:

```
List<dynamic> prods = new List<dynamic>();

            foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
                IDictionary<string, object> oprops = obj;

                foreach (System.Data.DataColumn col in dataTable.Columns)
                    oprops.Add(col.ColumnName, row[col.ColumnName]);
                obj = oprops;
                list.Add(obj);
            }
```

And `pricing` list is filled the same way from the `DataTable` having product pricing.

I have this query:

```
var result = (from product in prods join price in pricing on product.ID equals price.ProductID select new { product, price }).ToList();
```

And I want to add some more properties to the result set.

```
    foreach (dynamic obj in q)
    {
        obj.Test = "yes, testing."; // This line gives runtime error
        Console.WriteLine(
            "{0} - {1}",
            obj.product.Name,
            obj.price.UnitPrice);
    }
```

I have some more objects/values to add to the each individual result object in foreach loop.

I am just unable to do that as it throws runtime error as follows:

```
<>f__AnonymousType1<dynamic,dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'Test' and no extension method 'Test' accepting a first argument of type '<>f__AnonymousType1<dynamic,dynamic>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the property while querying the data so it is there to set in the foreach loop; eg:

```
var result = (from product in prods
                join price in pricing on product.ID equals price.ProductID
                select new { product, price, Test = (string)null, }
             ).ToList();
```

or, something I've never tried, maybe use an [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx):

```
var result = (from product in prods
                join price in pricing on product.ID equals price.ProductID
                select new ExpandoObject { product, price }
             ).ToList();
```

Comment: hmm, your first example is almost not a good idea and I would prefer to add the properties later in foreach loop depending upon the object type, doing it in Linq is not what I am looking.

Comment: and, your second example gives Compiler Error Message: CS0117: 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a definition for 'Add'

Comment: Sorry the second example doesn't work, like I said, I haven't actually needed to do something like that.  The only other option then is not to use an anonymous class, and use a class that has the properties that you want.

Comment: Thanks Chris, so if you look back the the query you would notice that i am joining two different lists to form a new result set that contains new {product, price} object. I have tried converting it back to dynamic it didnt help. May be there is anther way around. Like I said, I cant have a predefined class containing the predefined properties. the need is that the product object will be dynamically expanding at runtime to add more properties to be available for later use.This objects will be hopping from one custom code to another to fill developers need as there are 100s of developers working

Comment: Dynamic doesn't mean that you can get/set any property, it just means the get/set call will be performed at runtime and the compiler won't give you errors for missing properties; Casting an anonymous class to dynamic therefore doesn't let you add new properties.  It really sounds like what you need is an ExpandoObject for the result - You should continue experimenting with that (the second code sample).  Or use the approach you found of building another list and instantiating new objects for it.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is what I have found, we cant expand the linq query result set however creating a new exapndo objects solves the problem which enables adding new properties.

This is actually what I did:

```
List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();
            foreach (var o in q)
            {
                dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject();
                IDictionary<string, object> oprops = obj;
                oprops.Add("Test", "yes, testing!");
                oprops.Add("product", o.product);
                oprops.Add("price", o.price);
                obj = oprops;
                list.Add(obj);
            }
```